# How many humans have been living on earth that I could be born?

Tags: math

The formula for the calculation of the amount of humans per generation is 2^n

```
n   2^n    
0   1       that's me
1   2       this is the count of my parents (father + mother)
2   4       this is the count of my grand-parents
```

and so on

Assuming that every generation creates the next one with the age of 20 then we have in 2000 years 100 generations, that means:

```
n   2^n  
100 1.267.650.600.228.229.401.496.703.205.376 humans has been living on earth!
```

And now I am reading in wikipedia: The population on earth is today estimated 7.3 billion.

Comparing these to numbers is amazing:

```
1.267.650.600.228.229.401.496.703.205.376
                            7.600.000.000
```

Is this possible or did I make a mistake?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming. Perhaps it might be slightly better if it actually included a code snippet, but I'm not sure even that will help much.

Comment: ups, sorry. I don't wanted to put in the topic "programming". Can the admin move this threat to a better place for, please. e.g. biology

Comment: I don't know the Biology site, but glancing at it, it seems more academic than this question. I was also looking at Genealogy but that seems to be about more specific aspects of family trees.

Comment: Possibly related to http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/average-number-of-ancestors and http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-many-ancestors-alive-1000-years-ago-does-a-person-have-on-average

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations seem to be correct but you are missing some important factors.

The most critical miss is that you are assuming that all these ancestors must be distinct – that one person cannot occupy two different places in your family tree.

In most families you will find fairly recent examples of cousins marrying each other, especially if you use the wider definition of cousin that isn't restricted to First Cousins.

This significantly reduces the number of ancestors in your tree.

There is a saying that, after enough generations, either everybody on Earth will be your descendent, or else nobody will be, and there is a lot of truth in this.

We are all one big family when you think of it that way!

This is a well-known phenomenon, and is referred to as [Pedigree Collapse](http://www.isogg.org/wiki/Pedigree_collapse)

Comment: This is correct, my brother! ^^ But the grand number will only shrink a little bit if I would consider the inner relationships between ancestors. And this grand number is neccessary only for MY existence! The real number for all men on earth has to be multiplied by seven point 3 billions!! Did they have enough place on the earth?! ^^

Comment: Absolutely not. We are all related one way or another. There is only a problem if you assume there is no duplication anywhere. My brother's tree is basically identical to mine, and my cousin duplicates half of my tree.

Comment: ok, then I would calc the last 200 generations... ^^ The functions "ends" in the infinity!

Comment: If a model or hypothesis of the world is falsifyed a new model has to be invented to declare how the world is build. The model that we live in a matrix is really worth considering. The conclusion is that we are no human beeings rather than artifical intelligences... What changes? Nothing! ^^